# Jquery event not triggering on manually added elments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Page makes an ajax call, recieves JSON, than adds json data to new elements and those elements are appended to page:

```
$('.get_comments').on "ajax:complete", (e, data, status) ->
    json = data.responseJSON
      for obj in json
        $('.existing_div').append("<div class="APPENDED">#{obj.attr}</div>")
```

I have some 'on' listners for manually added elements but they're not triggering!

```
$('.APPENDED').on "click", ->
    console.log 'worked'
```

I do understand that it's beacuse of 'ready' does'nt see newly added elements. P.S. on page:change, page:update, it doesn't work either.
How do i solve this?

Comment: Do you set the listener after or before adding the new divs manually? If you always add the div and set the listener right after it should work.

Comment: I add it after the AJAX resolving function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching event handlers directly to the elements won't work for dynamically added elements. 
You should attach the handlers to the parent containers instead.

Try this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".APPENDED", function() {
  console.log ('worked');
});
```

Or,

```
$(document).on("click", ".APPENDED", function() {
   console.log ('worked');
});
```

In coffeescript:

```
$(document).on "click", ".APPENDED", ->
  console.log 'worked'
```

It should work.

Read more about this: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve the problem.
1. The easier way
Event delegation, you can read about it here http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$('.existing_div').on('click', '. APPENDED', function(){
    // do something
});
```

2. Before append do this

```
var elem = '<div class="APPENDED">#{obj.attr}</div>';
elem = $(elem);
elem.on('click', function(){
    // do something
});
$('.existing_div').append(elem);
```

Comment: 2'nd suggestion is best option I think. BTW if I'll use `this` in first option will it represent the triggered element (.appended)?- as it would do in second option?

Comment: I am not sure, but it should be `.existing_div`. try it out, just trigger the event and `console.log(this)`